# Do I really need to use a macro to execute a simple command remotely?

Tags: teraterm

All I want to do is run a script file on a remote system from the command line (so as to be able to automate it), and have its output displayed at stdout. I have looked at the [ttssh command line](https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/commandline/ttssh.html), and it seems I cannot - as e.g. with the openssh `ssh` command - simply provide a command like in the following

```
ssh otherbox /bin/ls
```

Someone told me it is possible with macros, which I haven't looked into yet. Is that really necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems like macros are the way, but what's worse, I can't seem to

- run it without the GUI popping up
- pipe the remote stdout to the local terminal

One way to run such a macro would be

```
ttermpro ssh://user:pass@otherbox /user=user /auth=pass /M=ls.ttl
```

and `ls.ttl` could look like this, using teraterm's log feature to capture the remote stdout to a file.

```
logopen 'log.txt' 0 1 1
wait '$'

send '/bin/ls'
send #10

send 'logout'
send #10
```